# How long is the eBay oauth token (and refresh token)?

Tags: ebay-api

I want to store the access token and refresh token in a database, so I need to know how big to make the fields.

eBay says about access tokens at https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/features-guide/content/basics/Tokens-About.html:

> - It can be up to 2KB in length and is base 64 encoded
> - It can contain: a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, asterisk, slash, plus ( * / +)

But actually, access tokens look like this:

```
v^1.1#i^1#f^0#r^0#p^3#I^3#t^H4sIAAAAAAAAAO[TRUNCATED FOR SECURITY]4fT+OfsMt2898RAAA=
```

There's a lot of characters at the start that don't match `[A-Za-z0-9*/+]`, and an `=` at the end, although it looks like the middle does actually match that. So how long can it be, really?

And what about refresh tokens?

Answer (score 0):

The authorization code is a maximum of 1024 characters in length.

Comment: what is your source?

Comment: @Ollie Please take a look on the following link: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-auth-code-grant-request.html